# Initial Value Problem with 2 solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following initial-value problem has two solutions: $x'=x^{\frac{1}{3}}, x(0)=0$. Verify that the two solutions are $x_1(t)=0$ and $x_2(t)=(\frac{2}{3}t)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ for $t\ge0$. If the Taylor series method is applied, what happens?

I verified $x_2(t)=(\frac{2}{3}t)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ through separation of variables and integrating with respect to $t$, but I don't know how to get $x_1(t)=0$ as a solution.

Comment: A more interesting problem is why the solution is not unique. The function, $f(t,x) = x^{1/3}$ is not globally Lipschitz. Where does this property not hold? If the initial problem was $x(t)$ with $t>0$ then would the solution be unique? On what interval? I leave you these questions to ponder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Drake:

If the initial value problem gives $x(0) = 0$, then $\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = 0$. So there is an obvious equilibrium solution where $x(t) = 0$ $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ to the IVP.

If the initial value problem was $x(\pi)=0$, then $\forall t\geq0, x(t) =0$. Similarly, if $x(\pi)\neq0$, then $x(t) = (2t/3)^{3/2}, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}^+$. The argument is similar for $t<0$. I urge you to look at what goes wrong at $x=0$; that is the Lipschitz property does not hold.